# Pack consecutive duplicates of list elements into sublists

Tags: list, prolog

I need some help. I searched through the database and I [found one question already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855146/pack-consecutive-duplicates-of-list-elements-into-sublists-in-prolog) about this example, but the answers didn't really help me, so I thought to post my own question.

The task is to pack consecutive duplicates of list elements into sublists:

```
% ?- pack([a,a,a,a,b,c,c,a,a,d,e,e,e,e],X).
% X = [[a,a,a,a],[b],[c,c],[a,a],[d],[e,e,e,e]].
```

Here is what I got:

```
pack([], []).
pack([X], [[X]]).
pack(Liste, Ergebnis):-
   Liste = [H, T|TS],
   H \= T,
   pack([T|TS], Ergebnis1),
   append([[H]], Ergebnis1, Ergebnis).
pack([H, H|HS], Ergebnis):-
   pack([H|HS], Ergebnis1),
   append([H|HS], Ergebnis1, Ergebnis).
```

The first case works really well (case where H \= T). The second one doesn't, and I really don't know why. Could someone please help me and explain the problem according my solution?

Thanks

Comment: How do I post a reference? By posting the link

Comment: ... consecutive duplicates ...: Why is `b` a consecutive duplicate in `[a,a,a,a,b,c,c,a,a,d,e,e,e,e]`?

Comment: b isn't a consecutive duplicate, it's only an example to show how the result should look like.

Comment: But your problem statement only talks about consecutive duplicates in the second argument. So why is `b` there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your forth clause tries to append `[H|HS]` to the result, which is incorrect, because `[H|HS]` is the tail of the original list. You can make it a lot simpler -

```
pack([H, H|HS], [[H|TFR]|TR]):-
    pack([H|HS], [TFR|TR]).
```

Essentially, it says that when the first two entries are the same in the input, the first entry (i.e. `H`) needs to be pre-pended to the first entry of the output list produced by recursive invocation of the `pack` rule.

Note that the third clause can be simplified as well by replacing the `Liste` parameter which you "crack" right away with the "cracked" version "inlined" into the header of the clause, and doing the same to the output variable `Ergebnis1`. The final version should look like this:

```
pack([H, T|TS], [[H]|TR]):-
    H \= T,
    pack([T|TS], TR).
```

[Here is a demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/4W4lgB)

Comment: hey :D thank you for your help. Can you explain what you mean by this [[H|TFR]|TR] to me? I do not "really" understand what the program does. Does TFR mean Tail from Rest? Sometimes I think to complicated when I'm trying to learn Prolog.

Comment: @user3637666 `[[H|TFR]|TR]` is a list. Its first entry is a list, too. The first entry of that "inner list" is `H`, the head of the input list (which also equals the second entry of the input list); the tail of the "inner list" is `TFR`, which is the head entry returned from the recursive invocation. The tail of the *outer* list is `TR`, i.e. the tail of the output list returned from the recursive invocation.

Answer (score 3):

The first two clauses are trivial cases and look good.

The third clause seems reasonable. It says that if I pack `[H,T|TS]` and `H \= T`, then the result would be `[H]` prepended to the result of `[T|TS]` being packed.

The forth clause is the problem:

```
pack([H, H|HS], Ergebnis):-
    pack([H|HS], Ergebnis1),
    append([H|HS], Ergebnis1, Ergebnis).
```

It says that the result of packing `[H,H|HS]` is the same as packing `[H|HS]` and then prepending all of `[H|HS]`. That doesn't seem logical. What's going to happen when you pack `[H|HS]` is you're going to get something that looks like: `[[H,...,H]|X]` and now you want to put another `H` into the head of the first sublist. So you should have:

```
pack([H, H|HS], Ergebnis):-
    pack([H|HS], [HH|T]),
    Ergebnis = [[H|HH]|T].
```

You can make these predicates a little more compact:

```
pack([], []).
pack([X], [[X]]).
pack([H,T|TS], [[H]|PTS]):-
   H \= T,
   pack([T|TS], PTS).
pack([H, H|HS], [[H|HH]|T]):-
   pack([H|HS], [HH|T]).
```

Testing...

```
| ?- pack([a,a,a,a,b,c,c,a,a,d,e,e,e,e],X).

X = [[a,a,a,a],[b],[c,c],[a,a],[d],[e,e,e,e]] ? a

no
| ?-
```

Comment: when you say Ergebnis = [[H|HH]|T], what does this mean? I don't know this form of syntax. Are you saying that the Head contains a head and a Tail?

Comment: @user3637666 It means you have a list whose head is a list, `[H|HH]`, and its tail is `T`. In Prolog, you can embed as many lists as you like. So `[H|T]` is a list with head `H` and tail `T`. If `H` itself is a list (such as in a list of lists), then `H` would either be empty `[]` or a list itself consisting of a head and a tail.

Comment: the shorter version having also a big advantage of being [TRMC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons) - potentially. I wonder how is it *really* compiled...

Comment: @WillNess: The problem in current implementations with above code is indexing. But otherwise, they all use constant space "for the recursion".

Comment: @lurker : thank you very much. Can you give me a tip how I could come straight to solutions when programming in Prolog? As I said: often I think that I think to complicated. I think I would never have come to your solution with: [[H|TFR]|TR].

Comment: @false thanks. Makes perfect sense too. I keep thinking about it in terms of manual rewrites with boxes and pointers, but in Prolog it all comes naturally.

Comment: @user3637666 there are two aspects of it. Very generally, a starting point in thinking about predicates is to try to express them in logical but natural language for the first level "what makes sense". As far as something like `[[H|TFR]|TR]`, that's just a syntactic thing. We're dealing with lists of lists here, so a list, which is either empty (`[]`) or a head and tail (`[H|T]`, where `H` is an element and `T` is the rest of the list) would imply that `H` itself is a list, so it can also be of the form `[H|T]`. Mash them together and you get `[[H|TFR]|TR]`.

Comment: @lurker what should I change, if I do not want to put in an element in a sublist which is not consecutive?

Comment: @johnjohn if you're asking about a variation of this problem, you should open a new question and show what you've tried and you will get some answers.

Comment: @lurker I solved it but I do not know how to explain it. I changed the 3rd predicate to : `group([H,T|TS], [H|PTS]):- H \= T, group([T|TS], PTS).` Could you explain to me in a few words why this works?

Comment: Your change doesn't quite work. For example, the query: ` pack([a,a,a,b], L).` results in, `L = [[a,a|a],[b]]`. Note in this result, instead of the first element being `[a,a,a]` you have `[a,a|a]` which isn't the same thing. `a` is being used as a tail here, but `a` is not a list. For example, if you did, `member(b, [a,b|c])` you would get "true", but `member([c, [a,b|c])` would yield "false". The flaw is that your change sometimes treats a non-list element as a list. Why did you make the change? What do you want to achieve by it?

Comment: @lurker I tested to the query which was given in the exercise and it worked for that. I did not test it for other cases. That was the predicate which I tested with the altered code above `?- group([1,1,1,1,2,c,c,1,1,d,e,e,e,e],X).
`

Comment: @johnjohn it might work for a couple of examples, but I am saying that it's an erroneous implementation since it will produce incorrect results for other valid cases. Just working for a couple of examples doesn't make code correct.

Answer (score 2):

*Every* of the other implementations given in answers to this question is *logically impure*. They are not monotone and thus easily become logically unsound when used with non-ground terms.

The implementation suggested here is **logically pure**. It uses the  meta-predicate [splitlistIfAdj/3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915), which is based on `if_/3`, as proposed by @false in [an answer on reification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915).

So let's use `splitlistIfAdj/3` in tandem with `dif/3` which is a reified variant of `dif/2`:

```
?- splitlistIfAdj(dif,[a,a,a,a,b,c,c,a,a,d,e,e,e,e],Lists).
Lists = [[a,a,a,a],[b],[c,c],[a,a],[d],[e,e,e,e]]. % succeeds deterministically
```

As we stay **monotone** here, 
we get meaningful answers even if we use non-ground terms:

```
?- splitlistIfAdj(dif,[A,B,C],Lists).
A = B,    B = C,    Lists = [[C, C, C]]    ;
A = B,    dif(B,C), Lists = [[B, B], [C]]  ;
dif(A,C), B = C,    Lists = [[A], [C, C]]  ;
dif(A,B), dif(B,C), Lists = [[A], [B], [C]].
```

Answer (score 1):

I would approach the problem a little differently and decompose the problem into two simpler tasks.

We first need to be able to partition the list into a *prefix* consisting of the list of consecutive elements at the head of the list and its *suffix* (everything else):

```
partition( []      , []    , []     ) .
partition( [X]     , [X]   , []     ) .
partition( [X,Y|Z] , [X]   , [Y|Z]  ) :- X \= Y .
partition( [X,Y|Z] , [X|P] , S      ) :- X  = Y , partition([Y|Z],P,S) .
```

Once we have that, the rest is easy:

```
pack([],[]) .               % packing an empty list yields the empty list
pack([X|Xs],[P,Ps]) :-      % packing a non-empty list consists of
  partition([X|Xs],P,T) ,   % - partitioning it into its prefix and suffix, and
  pack(T,Ps)                % - packing the suffix
  .                         %
```

Comment: I think it should be `pack([X|Xs],[P|Ps]) :- ...`.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid append, you can use [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg):

```
pack(L, LP) :-                  % pack/2
    phrase(pack(L), LP).

pack([]) --> [].                % pack//1
pack([X]) --> [[X]].
pack([H, H1 | T]) -->
     {H \= H1},
     [[H]],
     pack([H1 | T]).
pack([H, H | T]) -->
    pack([H | T], [H]).

pack([H, H | T], P) -->         % pack//2
    pack([H | T], [H|P]).
pack([H, H1 | T], P) -->
    {H \= H1},
    [[H | P]],
    pack([H1 | T]).
pack([H, H], P) -->
    [[H,H|P]].
```

Comment: If you used `dif/2` instead of `(\=)/2`, your code would perserve [tag:logical-purity]!